# Два в одном. Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Суспензия "два в одном".

Как написать правильно, если "два в одном" – это не название.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, имеется в виду суспензия, созданная по принципу (методу) "два в одном", суспензия типа "два в одном". Поэтому пишем:

**Суспензия "два в одном".**